# Lucene Taxonomy Writer Overflowing?

Tags: solr, lucene, bigdata

I have a Lucene index with over 120 million records in it and it has been working smoothly and quickly up to this point. However, today I started receiving:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -65536
lemur   at org.apache.lucene.util.ByteBlockPool.setBytesRef(ByteBlockPool.java:308)
lemur   at org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRefHash.equals(BytesRefHash.java:183)
lemur   at org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRefHash.findHash(BytesRefHash.java:330)
lemur   at org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRefHash.find(BytesRefHash.java:319)
lemur   at org.apache.lucene.facet.taxonomy.writercache.UTF8TaxonomyWriterCache.get(UTF8TaxonomyWriterCache.java:65)
lemur   at org.apache.lucene.facet.taxonomy.directory.DirectoryTaxonomyWriter.addCategory(DirectoryTaxonomyWriter.java:411)
lemur   at org.apache.lucene.facet.FacetsConfig.processFacetFields(FacetsConfig.java:322)
lemur   at org.apache.lucene.facet.FacetsConfig.build(FacetsConfig.java:285)
```

I don't know if this is due to memory issues, the 22gig index, or something else, but digging through this trace it has something to do with the taxonomy writer cache system.  I've validated that this is not consistently happening with the same record, but seems like some sort of memory overflow issue.  Unfortunately, I have no idea what to do from here or if I'm even on the right track of understanding the actual problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some additional digging I was able to figure out that `UTF8TaxonomyWriterCache` is not a good caching mechanism for big data. After switching to using `LruTaxonomyWriterCache` everything is working smoothly again.